# MVC4 Deployment in IIS 7.5 Windows 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, web-deployment

I have Developed a MVC4 Application and Deployed in IIS 7.5 in Windows 7.

Before Deploying i ran `aspnet_regiis - i` and published using VS 2012.

After Deploying in IIS 7.5 i was able to **open the Home page successfully** and tat is not the end of the story as i thought !

Now i have few ajax call to fetch Data were am not getting any results. And i tried in Firebug to see what happens and am getting "`Error Summary HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found`" and Error code:    0x80070002.

Then i compared the Header section from Locahost and IIS and i dont see much Difference.

I added `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` in my web.config.

PS: EveryThing looks fine if i run Locally but not in IIS.and have installed IIS in my Local Machine.

Do i need to add anything or any suggestion on how to Fix will be much Appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you installed MVC4 on the IIS server?

Comment: Are you able to access those ajax urls properly if you enter that in your browser?

Comment: @David I have IIS Configured in my Local Machine

Comment: @KD I click save and it hits the Jquery function and it returns 404 in IIS and if i do in Local host am getting Data

Comment: @KD is right. What URL do you get 404 on? Does that url seem right? Have you tried to directly access that URL in your browser?

Comment: @user2067567 I know MVC4 has a separate installation program from Asp.Net, I am pretty sure it doesn't come installed as part of IIS or .net framework, so if you didn't install it, probably isn't there. http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4